# analyzing assembly code of some c++ code

Tags: c++, assembly

I were asked to analyze an assembly code, which was generated from following c++ code in Visual studio IDE:

here is c++ code:

```
    int plus(int a,int b);

int main()
{
    cout<<plus(2,4);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}

int plus(int a,int b)
{
    static int t=2;
    return a+b+t;
}
```

And here is the assembly code (the reduced form):

```
_main   PROC                        ; COMDAT

; 8    : {

    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 192                ; 000000c0H
    push    ebx
    push    esi
    push    edi
    lea edi, DWORD PTR [ebp-192]
    mov ecx, 48                 ; 00000030H
    mov eax, -858993460             ; ccccccccH
    rep stosd

; 9    :    cout<<plus(2,4);

    push    4
    push    2
    call    ?plus@@YAHHH@Z              ; plus
    add esp, 8
    mov esi, esp
    push    eax
    mov ecx, DWORD PTR __imp_?cout@std@@3V?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@1@A
    call    DWORD PTR __imp_??6?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@QAEAAV01@H@Z
    cmp esi, esp
    call    __RTC_CheckEsp

; 10   :    getchar();

    mov esi, esp
    call    DWORD PTR __imp__getchar
    cmp esi, esp
    call    __RTC_CheckEsp

; 11   :    return 0;

    xor eax, eax

; 12   : }

    pop edi
    pop esi
    pop ebx
    add esp, 192                ; 000000c0H
    cmp ebp, esp
    call    __RTC_CheckEsp
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret 0
_main   ENDP
; Function compile flags: /Odtp /RTCsu /ZI
_TEXT   ENDS
;   COMDAT ?plus@@YAHHH@Z
_TEXT   SEGMENT
_a$ = 8                         ; size = 4
_b$ = 12                        ; size = 4
?plus@@YAHHH@Z PROC                 ; plus, COMDAT

; 15   : {

    push    ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    sub esp, 192                ; 000000c0H
    push    ebx
    push    esi
    push    edi
    lea edi, DWORD PTR [ebp-192]
    mov ecx, 48                 ; 00000030H
    mov eax, -858993460             ; ccccccccH
    rep stosd

; 16   :    static int t=2;
; 17   :    return a+b+t;

    mov eax, DWORD PTR _a$[ebp]
    add eax, DWORD PTR _b$[ebp]
    add eax, DWORD PTR ?t@?1??plus@@YAHHH@Z@4HA

; 18   : }

    pop edi
    pop esi
    pop ebx
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
    ret 0
?plus@@YAHHH@Z ENDP                 ; plus
_TEXT   ENDS
END
```

I have to find how does the code deal with stack and how variables stored and retrieved?
Regards.

Comment: The code is self explanatory . Do you have some specific questions ?

Comment: i want to know where the parameters a and b and also static int t stored. cant find them.

Comment: a and b are stored on stack. since those are parameters, you can see them being accessed here using ebp pointer:  
mov eax, DWORD PTR _a$[ebp]
add eax, DWORD PTR _b$[ebp]

t is directly specified as a constant in this instruction:
 add eax, DWORD PTR ?t@?1??plus@@YAHHH@Z@4H

Comment: and how about static int t and how does the control returns from plus method ?

Comment: t is a constant, I have already shown in my above reply. the two consecutive add instructions are adding a+b+t and storing result in eax instruction. "ret 0" is return instruction from plus method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the complete tutorial:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/reversedisasm.aspx

Please ask a specific question if you have ? Your original question is too broad.

Comment: finding the location of parameters and how does the control back from plus method are my main questions.

Answer (score 2):

> push    4
>
> push    2
>
> call    ?plus@@YAHHH@Z

This pushes the values 4 and 2 onto the stack (reverse order to how you'd think of them in C, remember 2 is now on top of 4), then calls plus.

> mov eax, DWORD PTR _a$[ebp]
>
> add eax, DWORD PTR _b$[ebp]
>
> add eax, DWORD PTR ?t@?1??plus@@YAHHH@Z@4HA
>
> pop edi
>
> pop esi
>
> pop ebx
>
> mov esp, ebp
>
> pop ebp
>
> ret 0

I've ignored some stack fiddling at the top of plus, but this moves a from the stack into eax, adds b to it (which it gets from the stack) then adds t to it (I'm not familiar with MASM at all so I'm not actually sure where it gets t from). You can see the stack offsets of a and b have been stored into _a and _b as 8 and 12 further up the code. This is performed in %eax because this is where you stick the first return value of a function. There's some stack clearing and then the usual function epilogue before returning. The main code then pushes %eax onto the stack and calls the iostream stuff, which will pop it off and output it to screen.